# C# MEF dependency injection: the classes in the module cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

I want to use MEF to achieve dependency injection. However, when trying to load all the different .dll files it always runs into the an System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded. This occurs when trying to load "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll".

I'm trying to do this on a mac, using the mono compiler and the target framework set at: .NET Framework 4.5.2

```
    #region Constructor
    public ModuleConfigurationCatalog()
    {
        var assemblyUri = new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath));
        var assemblyDir = assemblyUri.LocalPath;

        var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(assemblyDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var assemblies = allFiles.Where(f => f.EndsWith(".dll", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || f.EndsWith(".exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Distinct();

        _catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

        foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
        {
            var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(assembly);

            if (assemblyCatalog.Parts.ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                _catalog.Catalogs.Add(assemblyCatalog);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

[breakpoint information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gabp2.png)

[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHKeo.png)

Comment: You're probably missing a dependency of the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll` assembly.  Make sure all of its dependencies exist in the same folder.  (Or maybe load it from the GAC if it exists there... not sure how to do that with MEF, though.)

Comment: @wablab Thanks, I added all the dependencies to the references and that solved the problem.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so that you can accept it to close out the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a dependency of the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll` assembly.  Make sure all of its dependencies exist in the same folder.  (Or maybe load it from the GAC if it exists there... not sure how to do that with MEF, though.)